# pandas return value of index based on unique value on row

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a list of id's that I need to link to a dictionary value for further analysis. The ids are unique, but aren't the index value for the dataframe I'm using as a basis.

If that is confusing, I'm trying read in a value from a list and link that to a value on the id column on a dataframe and use the index from that row in the dataframe to access a dictionary.

My first attempt:

```
def getIndex(value):
return pageData[pageData['id'] == value].index
```

This worked to an extent, that it returned the correct index, but not in a way that I could use immediately. Could I manipulate my code a bit to just return the index value and not the dtype? Or is there an even better way of doing this?

Sample Data:

```
list = ["1wrg", "2oij", "3dete"]

df = [{ "index" = 0, "id" = "1wrg"}, {"index" = 1, "id" = "2oij"}, {"index" = 2, "id" = "3dete"}]
 //Should be worth mentioning that the index's aren't explicit in the dataframe, there are just here 
// to add some clarity to my problem


dictionary = { 0 : [1,2],
               1 : [0],
               2 : [0],
             }
```

expected result:

getIndex returns correct index so I can use it as a key to get the correct value from the dictionary

Actual Result:

```
Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
def getIndex(value):
    return pd.Index(df['id']).get_loc(value)
```

Pretty easy once you know how

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it seems to work correctly:

1. getIndex return Index object and you can convert it to list:

   q = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':3,'b':5}])

   ind = (q[q['a'] == 1]).index

   ind_list = list(ind)
2. More than 1 index can be in result, also empty object is possible depending on values.

   empty = list( (q[q['a'] == 100]).index)

After accessing correct index with (like first one with `ind_list[0]`) you shall be able to use it for dictionary.